# Special summation of integer array elements

Tags: c#, array, rags-to-riches

I looked at this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60975/18427) and thought that I could find a much simpler way of doing this, here is the criteria that was given:

> My current task is to find a score from an array where the highest/lowest scores have been taken away, and if the highest/lowest occur more than once (ONLY if they occur more than once), one of them can be added:
>
> E.g. `int[] scores = [4, 8, 6, 4, 8, 5]`
>
> therefore the final addition will be \$\sum{4,8,6, 5} = 23 \$.
>
> Another condition of the task is that LINQ cannot be used, as well as any of the `System.Array` methods

Here is what I came up with: ([Link to Answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/61023/18427))

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // take an array and sum the distinct numbers
    int[] numberArray = { 4, 8, 6, 4, 8, 5 };
    int[] numberArray2 = { 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8 };

    Console.WriteLine(sumSpecial(numberArray).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(sumSpecial(numberArray).ToString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static int getHighestScore(int[] integerArray)
{
    var high = 0;
    foreach (int number in integerArray)
    {
        high = high < number ? number : high;
    }
    return high;
}

static int getLowestScore(int[] integerArray)
{
    var low = int.MaxValue;
    foreach (int number in integerArray)
    {
        low = low > number ? number : low;
    }
    return low;
}

static int sumWithoutHighAndLowScores(int[] integerarray)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int high = getHighestScore(integerarray);
    int low = getLowestScore(integerarray);
    foreach (int number in integerarray)
    {
        if (number != high && number != low)
        {
            sum += number;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

//sum of numbers using high or low only if there is a duplicate of high or low
static int sumSpecial(int[] integerArray)
{
    var sum = sumWithoutHighAndLowScores(integerArray);
    var high = getHighestScore(integerArray);
    var low = getLowestScore(integerArray);

    var highs = 0;
    var lows = 0;
    foreach (int number in integerArray)
    {
        if (number == high) { highs++; }
        if (number == low) { lows++; }
    }
    if (lows > 1) { sum += low; }
    if (highs > 1) { sum += high; }

    return sum;
}
```

What could be done better or more efficiently without losing the intentions of the exercise?

Comment: Why can't you use linq or `System.Array`?

Comment: @slartidan, the Question I saw had those restrictions, so I followed suit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I think `min` and `max` are more descriptive names than `high` and `low`.
2. In C# the standard naming convention for methods is `PascalCase`.
3. You could save several iterations by doing the following things:

   - Create a single method for determining min and max in one go and return either a `Tuple` or a custom type or an array of length 2 or provide out parameters. If you don't want to use any more complex types than arrays then I'd probably go for `out` parameters (returning an array of a certain size doesn't seem very nice). So something along these lines:

     ```
     public void DetermineMinAndMax(int[] input, out int min, out int max)
     {
         min = Int32.Max;
         max = In32.Min;
         foreach (int number in input)
         {
             if (number < min) { min = number; }
             else if (number > max) { max = number; }
         }
     }
     ```
   - Keep counters of how often you have seen the min/max already - if it's 1 add it otherwise skip. Something along these lines:

     ```
     public void SumSpecial(int[] input)
     {
         int min, max;

         DetermineMinAndMax(input, out min, out max);

         int countMinSeen = 0;
         int countMaxSeen = 0;

         int sum = 0;

         foreach (int number in input)
         {
             if (number == min)
             {
                 if (countMinSeen == 1) { sum += number; }
                 countMinSeen++;
             }
             else if (number == max)
             {
                 if (countMaxSeen == 1) { sum += number; }
                 countMaxSeen++;
             }
             else { sum += number; }
         }
     }
     ```

   This should reduce the number of required iterations to 2 instead of 4.

Comment: I have been mixed up all day today about the Method Naming, thank you for pointing that out. *facepalm*