# Summing up distinct elements in steps (follow up)

Tags: c#, algorithm, rags-to-riches

This is a "follow up" to an answer I gave on this question : [Summing up distinct elements in steps](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60975/summing-up-distinct-elements-in-steps/61009#61009)

Here are the OP's requirements :

> "My current task is to find a score from an array where the highest/lowest scores have been taken away, and if the highest/lowest occur more than once (ONLY if they occur more than once), one of them can be added:
>
> E.g. int[] scores = [4, 8, 6, 4, 8, 5] therefore the final addition will be ∑4,8,6,5=23.
>
> Another condition of the task is that LINQ cannot be used, as well as any of the System.Array methods (you can see by my previously ask questions that has been a bit of a pain for me, since I solved this with LINQ in less than 5 minutes)."

```
public int CalculateScore(int[] scores)
{
   int lowestValue = int.MaxValue,
   highestValue = int.MinValue,
   ammountOfHighestValue = 1,
   ammountOfLowestValue = 1,
   finalScore = 0;

   foreach (int score in scores)
   {
      finalScore += score;

      if (score < lowestValue)
      {
         lowestValue = score;
         ammountOfLowestValue = 1; //We need to reset the ammount
      }
      else if (score > highestValue)
      {
         highestValue = score;
         ammountOfHighestValue = 1; //We need to reset the ammount
      }
      else if (score == lowestValue)
         ammountOfLowestValue++;
      else if (score == highestValue)
         ammountOfHighestValue++;
   }

   if (ammountOfHighestValue > 1)
      //This way, we keep the highest score once.
      finalScore -= ((ammountOfHighestValue - 1) * highestValue); 
   else
      finalScore -= highestValue; //The value is there once, we remove it.

   if (ammountOfLowestValue > 1)
      finalScore -= ((ammountOfLowestValue - 1) * lowestValue); //Same as highest
   else
      finalScore -= lowestValue;

   return finalScore;
}
```

I'm interested about how can I remove the multiple if/else statements  <strike>while keeping a complexity of O(n)</strike> and still loop through the array only once.

Comment: It is important to realize that a complexity of going over an array multiple  times is still \$O(n)\$, as long as the number of passes is fixed (that is, doesn't depend on \$n\$). The performance difference between doing everything in one pass, or splitting job between dedicating passes is not measurable.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that, I'm just starting to learn big O notation. You mean, if I run trough the array a zillion times, notation is still O(n) right? (Just want to make sure, non-native english here)

Comment: Correct, if you can guarantee no more than the zillion runs regardless of the array size (think of multi-mega-gazillion-strong arrays).

Comment: That is super interesting! But if the array had a zillion elements, I believe looping it multiple times would hurt performance

Comment: SE has a policy against the discussion in comments. Let's continue on chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor

Comment: How do you define looping multiple times? LINQ could help here, but that's really just hiding the loops, however the code could look significantly cleaner that way.

Comment: I mean having more than one loop. And LINQ was prohibited in the OP's question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bugs**

```
Console.WriteLine(CalculateScore(new[] { 1 } ));
Console.WriteLine(CalculateScore(new[] { 2, 1 } ));
Console.WriteLine(CalculateScore(new[] { 3, 2, 1 } ));
```

What's the expected output? The question is maybe underspecified for the first case (I would say it's 0), but the other two are clear: 0 and 2.

But we get:

```
-2147483648
-2147483646
-2147483643
```

Bonus question: what is the correct result for the array `{ 1, 1 }`? I would say 2, but your program returns 0.

Comment: You are right, the OP didn't specify any criteria for these cases so I didn't think about them, but obviously my program is flawed

Comment: the output for the input `{1, 1}` should be **1** because there are two instances of the lowest number and two instances of the highest number.